# Broken Customizer page

Tags: wp-admin, theme-customizer, dashboard

​Hello!

The (Theme Customizer) is broken. The link from the menu disappeared and when I access it via the URL wp-admin/customize.php I got the attached error on my console.

Screenshot:
[image]

Things I tried without luck:

- Disabled all caching (Browser cache + object cache + CDN)
- Disabled <s>almost</s> **ALL** plugins. ALL
- Used the default theme 2021
- Reinstalled the whole WordPress (replaced the files only)
- No errors appear on error_log or debug.log files
- Added (‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false) to the config file even though I don’t know what does it mean but I read it somewhere.
- Added remove_action(‘shutdown’, ‘wp_ob_end_flush_all’, 1) to the theme’s function.php file and I don’t know what does it mean but I read it somewhere.
- Tried switching between PHP 7.4 and 7.3
- Tried different browsers

Still the same issue, and I don’t recall any specific change prior to the issue occurrence.

Environment:

- WordPress version 5.8.2
- Server: Apache & Ngnix
- PHP version: 7.4.26

Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this furthermore?

Best regards!

Update: It looks like all dashboard pages have some sort of console errors. Not only the customizer.

Comment: "almost all plugins"?

Comment: Also, have you tried `ctrl + f5`, a hard refresh?

Comment: @JacobPeattie at that time I kept only WooCommerce and Elementor. Now, tried disabling all. Zero active plugins. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast Yes, tried different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! Seems that there was a conflict in the .htaccess file. Even though all plugins were disabled, but their codes were not removed. (And now the plugins are not writing to it even though it's writable). And I don't manually edit the file.

So, restoring the .htaccess file to the cPanel + WordPress default solved the problem.